# How to execute multiple NCFTP commands in Windows batch file

Tags: ftp

I have created three lines of NCFTP sequentially in Windows batch file.

If I execute three lines of NCTP command in Windows batch file, only first line of the command is  etting executed. Second and third command is not executing.

Please let me know is there any way to execute multiple NCFTP commands in     Windows batch file?

Code which I have used in the batch file:

```
ncftp -u <user> -p <pass> website.com binary
ncftp -u <user> -p <pass> website.com  cd \20161221
ncftp -u <user> -p <pass> website.com  ls
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show some code.

Comment: ncftp -u <user> -p <pass>  website.com 
ncftp -u <user> -p <pass>  website.com cd Subdir
ncftp -u <user> -p <pass>  website.com ls

Comment: Edit this into your question, to make the code readable.

Comment: I added the code in my question. Only first line of my code is executing. It is not moving to second line of code. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The `ncftp` is an interactive tool. It's not designed for automation.

To automate directory listing, use the [`ncftpls`](https://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpls.html):

```
ncftpls -u <user> -p <pass> ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/to/list/
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux you use a `here document`:

```sh
ncftpls -u username -p password ftp://ftp.domain.com <<EOF
cd /path/to/files
dir
cd ..
dir
EOF
```

or simply a `here string`:

```sh
ncftpls -u username -p password ftp://ftp.domain.com <<<"cd /path/to/files;dir;cd ..;ls -al"
```

Maybe you can use it under `cygwin` on windows.

See more on `here documents` and `here strings` in the [bash documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)